How do I merge video, audio and subtitles together in ffmpeg via python?
I have been trying to merge a video, audio and subtitle stream in ffmepg but, since it is my first time trying it out, I am having a bit of trouble figuring out how to do so.
Goal: The output I am looking for a the video in the background with the subtitles overlayed in the center of the screen with the audio from the input stream, which in this case is an mp3 file.
These are my input streams:
video_input_stream = ffmpeg.input(background_video)
audio_input_stream = ffmpeg.input(audio)
subtitle_input_stream = ffmpeg.input(subtitle_file)

and I have successfully added sound to video like so:
ffmpeg.concat(video_with_subtitles, audio_input_stream, v=1, a=1)


and also subtitles like so:
ffmpeg.output(video_with_subtitles, output_video, vf=f"subtitles={subtitle_file}")

but not at the same time!
Thank you for helping.
